# No module named openpyxl - Python 3.6

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, openpyxl

I have virtual environment setup for my project, where i run python 3.6 with openpyxl module installed inside virtual enviroment.

I wrote a simple test program and when i run it within VIsual Studio Code editor i get this error:

```
No module named 'openpyxl'
```

However if i run the program from the command prompt, inside virtual environment, it executes without any error. I have configured Visual Studio Code to use my virtual environment path with this line:

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Nermin\\Desktop\\EA-Monthly-Report\\Scripts"
```

Why is Visual Studio Code complaining that the openpyxl module does not exist when that is not true?

```
'''Testing openpyxl modlue for python'''
from openpyxl import Workbook

def test_workbook():
    '''
    Testing openpyxl
    '''

    work_book = Workbook()
    work_sheet = work_book.active
    work_sheet.title = "EA Monthly Report"
    work_sheet['A1'] = 'Test Data'
    work_book.save('test.xlsx')

#Run program
test_workbook()
```

Comment: You need to setup Visual Studio to work with the virtualenv.

Comment: I thought that i did this, the way to set up Visual Studio Code with virtual environment is to set the path in settings.json which i have done.    "python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/Nermin/Desktop/EA-Monthly-Report/Scripts/python.exe"
}   Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I will share  and hope someone else might find this helpful with same issue that i was having.

The way i got it to work is to start Visual Studio Code from the activated virtual environment command prompt. After that i was able to execute the program within Visual Studio Code.

Visual Studio Code will configure its self for the virtual environment after you start it from active virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple python environments that might be causing the problem. You can install the package from within visual studio using the "manage packages" button next to the python environment selector